# Local object variable closure in loop

Tags: javascript, closures

I expect this code to console.log the same as number as displayed in a clicked element.
However, if I click any element, I get 9 in log (Chrome 60).

Why does this happen?

I know that `i` should not be used in a callback function because it is changed by the moment this event handler is executed.
But shouldn't `x` work correctly? `value` property is a primitive and `x` is a local variable, how can it be changed outside.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  var x = {
    value: i
  };
  
  $("<div/>").text(i).appendTo("body").click(function() {
    console.log(x.value);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It seems like using `let` solves this problem for me, but shouldn't `var` behave the same in this case with local variable?

Comment: I am getting 0 to 9 in the log when I run your code snippet

Comment: If you declare `x` with `let` instead of `var` your code would work. Variables declared with `var` are scoped at the function level, not the block level.

Comment: @marvel308 Oh...I have Ctrl+F5-ed twice, it won't help :( May be, a browser issue? I use Chrome 60.

Comment: It's not a browser issue; that's just how JavaScript works. The whole reason for the introduction of `let` declarations was exactly this issue!

Comment: the code snippet still works though @Pointy

Comment: @Pointy Thank you! I have switched to C# for a month or two and should have forgotten this JS feature. Documentations say that there is really no thing like "block scope" for `var` in JS, it is always function-scope.

Comment: @marvel308 It prints `9` for all  the generated elements. It that's supposed to happen then yes "the code snippet still works".

Comment: is this a bug, the snippet still prints 0 to 9 for me ?

Comment: @marvel308 the problem is with the *event handler*, not the code in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the `x` object to the dynamically created jQuery object using `.data()`, within `click` handler access the object using `$(this).data().value` or `$(this).data("value")`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var x = {
    value: i
  };

  $("<div/>")
  .data(x)
  .text(i)
  .appendTo("body")
  .click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data().value);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```